# Confused about DataBinding DatePicker in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying bind data from a datepicker to a variable such that it can be readily used in Typescript. Any ideas on this problem would be much appreciated

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">

<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Select Date

Answer (score 1):

MatDatePicker's contents need to be enclosed in a `<mat-form-field>`. See the following example from the [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples).

```
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this event `dateChange` or `dateInput` on the input tag that you can use in your ts file :

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
         (dateInput)="addEvent( $event)" (dateChange)="addEvent( $event)">
```